# Flink transformation which does REST call (async, Future, Netty)

Tags: asynchronous, netty, apache-flink

Let's assume that Flink receives a stream of 1000's of tweets per second and that somewhere in the process, it needs to classify them as spam or not. I have a cluster of e.g. 20 machines that provide the "classification" microservice through a REST API and they can give max throughput of 10k tweets per second and their latency is 3 seconds. This means that at worst case, I might have 30k tweets on the fly and that's ok. I guess that to consume this service from Flink, an implementation will be something like this:

```
public class Classifier implements MapFunction<Tweet, TweetWithClass> {
  @Override
  public TweetWithClass map(Tweet tweet) {
    TweetWithClass twc = new TweetWithClass(tweet);
    twc.classes = (new Post('http://my.classifier.com', data = tweet.body)).bodyAsStringArrayFromJson();
    return twc;
  }
}

DataSet<TweetWithClass> outTweets = inTweets.map(new Classifier()).setParallelism(30000);
```

Now, given this API, my guess is that Flink would have no other choice other than starting 30k threads and that would be potentially bad. I see in the source code that Flink uses Netty, I guess it could support this operation more efficiently by using asynchronous calls... If fictitious beautiful Netty, Flink and Java API existed, this would look something like this:

```
public class Classifier implements MapFunction<Tweet, TweetWithClass> {
  @Override
  public Future<TweetWithClass> map(Tweet tweet) {
    Future<String[]> classes = (new NettyPost('http://my.classifier.com', data = tweet.body)).asyncBodyAsStringArrayFromJson();
    return classes.onGet( (String[] classes) -> new TweetWithClass(tweet, twc.classes) );
  }
}

DataSet<TweetWithClass> outTweets = inTweets.nettyMap(new Classifier()).setMaxParallelism(30000);
```

Is there a way to use asynchronous calls to have massive scalability with very few threads in Flink?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know this is a relatively old question but as of Flink 1.2 (Which came out in February 2017), Flink offers an API for exactly this purpose. 
It's called async I/O.

With async I/O you can perform asynchronous calls to external databases or in your case external web service and get the results with a callback inside a future.

More Information can be found here: https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.3/dev/stream/asyncio.html

Comment: How to use in map function rather than as a datasource？